# How two different elements belong to a polynomial implies the polynomial is a proper ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This is an example from Galois Theory.

> If F is a field, then a nonzero polynomial p(x) ∈ F[x] is irreducible
>   if and only if (p(x)) is a prime ideal.
>
> proof:
>
> Suppose p(x) is irreducible.
>
> If ab ∈ p, then p | ab
>
> Euclid's lemma implies that p | a or p | b.
>
> Thus, a ∈ (p) or b ∈ (p).
>
> Finally, p is a proper ideal.

I'm ok with the prove till a ∈ (p) or b ∈ (p).

But then why p is a proper ideal? The question only give us p(x) is a polynomial in a field.

Comment: Bring irreducible usually means non-constant not just nonzero. Note that 1 cannot be in (p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is irreducible, then by definition it is not a unit, so $1\not\in (p)$ and $(p)$ is a proper ideal.

Comment: Well, seems the definition in Galois Theory doesn't state $p$ is not a unit if it is irreducible. But I'm still confused. The definition says An ideal $I$ in a Ring is a proper ideal if $I/not/equal R$. Why 1 $/not/in (p)$ implies $(p)$ is a proper ideal. What Ring are we comparing with $I$?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is making me nervous.  Irreducible usually means a non-unit $p$ with $p=ab \Rightarrow a\in U(R)$ or $b \in U(R)$ (for integeral domains).  Prime is a non-unit with $p\mid ab \Rightarrow p\mid a$ or $p \mid b$.  Euclid's lemma is for primes rather than irreducibles usually, but since the integers are a PID they are equivalent, so it is not that big of a deal, but outside of the integers, this causes some confusion I think.  Your use of Euclid's lemma seems to be essentially already assuming $p(x)$ is prime rather than irreducible.

Polynomial rings over a field are Euclidean Domains which are PIDs which are UFDs.  Even in a UFD, irreducible implies prime, but here I think the PID proof of irreducible implying prime is worth mentioning.

You can actually show if $p(x)$ is irreducible, then $(p(x))$ is maximal and hence prime.  Suppose $(p(x)) \subseteq I \subseteq F[x]$ with $p(x)$ irreducible.  Since $F[x]$ is a PID, $I=(f(x))$ for some $f(x)$.  But $p(x) \in I$, so $p(x)=f(x)g(x)$ for some $g(x)$.  Since $p(x)$ is irreducible, either $f(x)$ is a unit or $g(x)$ is a unit.  If $f(x)$ is a unit, then $I=(f(x))=F[x]$ since any ideal containing a unit, must be the whole ring.  If $g(x)$ is a unit, then $(p(x))=(f(x))$.  This shows $(p(x))$ is maximal.

Comment: It is the proof from the book... I only cut part of it till where I stuck.

Comment: What book? Do they prove Euclid's lemma for $F[x]$?  This is bizarre to me because in general it is definitely not true that $p$ being irreducible implies $p$ is prime ($p \mid ab \Rightarrow p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.) So outside of AP domains Euclid's lemma does not work on irreducible elements.

Comment: Galois Theory. I'm not sure if it prove Euclid's lemma. It is the textbook required for our course. But we are not required to read it completely as long as we go to the lecture.

Comment: Who is the author? That is a pretty common name for a book.  Here are some examples of irreducible elements which are not prime if you are interested. https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Irreducible_element_not_implies_prime

Comment: Thank you. It is in page 32 theorem 24, by Joseph Rotman, second edition.

Comment: Do you have a better resource to learn ring theory? I feel not comfortable with this book.

Comment: I liked Gallian's book for a very gentle introduction. Dummit and Foote is a nice one with lots of examples and problems to work, but is a bit tougher.  Kaplansky's book is where I learned, but I would not recommend starting with that one.

Comment: Oh!!!!!!!!! Contemporary Abstract Algebra, it is the book I learned group theory. I like that also.